# Enabled/disabled broadcastreceiver после ребута

Tags: android, service, broadcast-receiver, android-preferences

В приложении используется функция запуска сервиса после ребута (ее можно отключать /включать) . Код :

**Receiver:** В методе `onReceive`:

```
  App.getAppContext().startService(
                    new Intent(App.getAppContext(), MyService.class));
```

При нажатии контрола отключить/включить ресивер :

```
  ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(ctx,
                  Receiver.class);
            PackageManager packageManager = ctx.getPackageManager();
            int state = enabled ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED
                    : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
            packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                    state, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

В манифесте

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
```

Сложность состоит в том, что при ребуте устройства с Android 4.2.2 мое приложение отображается в списке выполняемых, хотя сервис не должен стартовать(положение контрола в preferences -disabled).
На других устройствах, на которых я тестировал приложение, все отрабатывало корректно. Когда контрол в состоянии вкл - сервис стартует при ребуте, если выкл - нет. 
В чем может быть причина такого поведения?